# Alias inside VirtualHost is not working and gives 404 error

Tags: apache, alias, virtualhost

I have a server which maintains multiple domains using `VirtualHost` and I'm trying to setup [*GitWeb*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb) according to [*Gitweb - ArchWiki*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitweb).

According to the wiki, I have to append the lines below to an Apache config file.

```html
Alias /gitweb "/usr/share/gitweb"
<Directory "/usr/share/gitweb">
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    <Files gitweb.cgi>
    SetHandler cgi-script
    </Files>
    SetEnv  GITWEB_CONFIG  /etc/gitweb.conf
</Directory>
```

After this, `Alias` works and I can access the service by accessing one of

- 192.168.10.102/gitweb/ (local IP)
- https://my_domain_1.com/gitweb/
- https://my_domain_2.com/gitweb/
- ...

So far, everything's okay.

Now I'd like to limit the effect of the `Alias` to one domain: `my_domain_1.com`. So I moved the lines above inside its existing `VirtualHost` settings.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html1"
    ServerName my_domain_1.com

    # The lines are pasted here.

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my_domain_1.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I access `https://my_domain_1.com/gitweb/`, 404 error occurs. The error log says nothing and I have no `.htaccess` for the domain.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Since I requested that all of `http` requests should be redirected to the `https` versions, I should have written the `gitweb` settings not in `<VirtualHost *:80>` (http) but in `<VirtualHost *:443>` (https). The result should be

```html
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html1"
    ServerName my_domain_1.com

    # The lines are pasted here.

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain_1.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain_1.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it works perfectly.